# Passing an Activity object using PutSerializable

Tags: android, serialization, android-activity

I'm trying to pass an `Activity` object using `putSerializable` method.

```
parameters.putSerializable("contextMenuActivity", (Serializable) caller);
//"caller" is an Activity
```

but I get this exception

```
 E/AndroidRuntime(4933): java.lang.RuntimeException: Parcel: unable to marshal value br.com.its4schools.activities.MyActivity@4256fd90
```

Someone has any idea?

Comment: what you need the whole activity serialized? looks like complete design misunderstanding for me

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can not serialize an `Activity`, Period. Also, there is no reason to do so. There is always a better way. What do you want to do? From where and why do you want to get it? For example if you need a reference to the Activity from within a `Fragment`, you can override the `onAttach(Activity)` method.